In macro "@k", using ^M at end of "call function()" executes the function, but also undesirably adds a new line to my text
I am running nVim v 0.10.1 on archlinux. Everything is up to date.
I am running this macro as defined in .vimrc:
let @k =  '\z:call CZC()'

But a carridge return is necesary to make this run, when I key @k so it becomes
let @k =  '\z:call CZC()^M'

This works but ^M executes two carridge returns

one run's the call function, and
one inserts a carridge return into my currently being edited text as a new line.

I only want one carridge return, that will execute @k not two.
How can I add the carridge return at the end of the macro, to run the macro, without adding a new line to my text?

This happens because when you use :let @ to set a register, it detects whether the register should be made linewise based on whether the value ends in a <NL> or <CR>.
See this part of :help :let-@:

If the result of {expr1} ends in a <CR> or <NL>, the
register will be linewise, otherwise it will be set to
characterwise.

The ultimate side effect of making a register linewise is that a <NL> is appended at the end.
You can see that with the :reg k command:
:reg k
Type Name Content
  l  "k   \z:call CZC()^M^J

The ^J is the added <NL>.
One way around this is using setreg(), in which case you can explicitly set the register to be characterwise even though the contents end with <CR>:
call setreg('k', '\z:call CZC()^M', 'c')

Or, slightly better, using \r in a double quoted string, that way your file doesn't need to have special characters and is less likely to be corrupted:
call setreg('k', "\\z:call CZC()\r", 'c')


filbranden has done a great job of explaining what causes the issue.
An alternative to using his suggestion of using setreg() is to end your macro with a Ctrl-J instead of a CTRL-M. You can do this either by typing Ctrl-VCtrl-J to enter it literally*, or with a string escape:
let @k =  "\\z:call CZC()\<C-J>"

You can then see with :reg k that this doesn't cause the :let command to add the additional character:
:reg k
Type Name Content
  l  "k   \z:call CZC()^J

The CTRL-J will still cause your command-line command to be executed, though, as desired.
*: Note that this will be notated as ^@ in the command-line. See :help NL-used-for-Nul.

It seems that it doesn't work on Windows.

@VivianDeSmedt Hmm. It's working fine for me in Windows gVim. What version are you using? What exact behaviour do you see?

I'm using gVim 9.1 including patch 1-474.

@VivianDeSmedt Which bit doesn't work? Does the :let command not set the register correctly? Or is the ex command not run? Or is the behaviour of the macro wrong in some other way? Does using a literal CTRL-J instead of the escaped version behave differently?

the :let works fine. I have the ^J at the end of the register when using the :reg command but when I run the macro @k the ^J doesn't trigger the execution of the command and I have in the command line: :call CZC() waiting an Enter key stroke to be validated.

I have tried with version 9.1 including patches 1-718 and I have the same behavior than with version 9.1 including patches 1-474 (the ^J is not validating the command).

@VivianDeSmedt Odd. Does this version work for you?: let @k =  "\\z:call CZC()\<CR>\<C-L>"

Yes indeed this version works fine. But I understand it is just a trick to avoid the trailing ^M by adding a trailing ^L that triggers a redraw (considered as a kind of "null" operation).
